# change input size depending on option selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, input

I've seen similar questions posted and tried to change them to meet my needs but I don't know enough about javascript to do it. All I want to do is limit a form input to 2 characters if they select "state" as their search option. This is what I have:

```
function changeValue(){
var option=document.getElementById('searchtype').id;

if (option == ("A") || ("B") ){
document.getElementById('field').size="40";
}
else if(option=="C"){
document.getElementById('field').size="2";


<form action="results.php" method="post">
Search By:<br />
<select id="searchtype" name="searchtype" onchange="changeValue();">
<option id="A" value="name">Hospital Name<br /></option>
<option id="B" value="city">City</option>
<option id="C" value="state">State</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Search:<br />
<input id="field" name="searchterm" type="text" size="0">
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this?

I used Jack's code below and added a field.size attribute so my input matched the max allowed characters: (thanks Jack)

```
script type="text/javascript">
function changeValue(dropdown) {
var option = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value,
field = document.getElementById('field');

if (option == 'name' || option == 'city') {
    field.maxLength = 40;
            field.size = 40;
} else if (option == 'state') {
    field.value = field.value.substr(0, 2); 
    field.maxLength = 2;
            field.size = 2;
}
}       
</script>

            <h1>Hospital Search</h1>
    <form action="results.php" method="post">
    Search By:<br />
    <select id="searchtype" name="searchtype" onchange="changeValue(this);">
    <option id="name" value="name">Hospital Name<br /></option>
    <option id="city" value="city">City</option>
    <option id="state" value="state">State</option>
    </select><br />
    Search:<br />
    <input id="field" name="field" type="text" size="40">
    </input>
```

After deciding a dropdown with a list of states would be better, I changed it to this:

```
<form action="results.php" method="post">
      Hospital Name:<br />
      <input name="searchterm_name" type="text" size="40">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
      </form><br />
        <form action="results.php" method="get">
        City Name:<br />
        <input name="searchterm_city" type="text" size="40"><br />
        <select name="select_state">
        <option value="">None
        <option value="AL" Selected>Alabama
        <option value="AK">Alaska
        <option value="AZ">Arizona
                    </SELECT>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
      </form>
```

ED: Using form method "post" caused the browser to throw a warning every time I hit the back button to get to the results page. I changed to "get" since the information is not sensitive and now it goes back w/o warning.

Comment: onchange of dropdown, you don't want to clear text box?

Comment: Yeah I suppose I probably would. I also just realize I should probably just give them a dropdown menu of states to choose from like most sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `maxlength` property:

```
document.getElementById('field').maxlength = 2;
```

I realize now that the rest of the code is not likely to work:

```
function changeValue(dropdown) {
    var option = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value,
    field = document.getElementById('field');

    if (option == 'name' || option == 'city') {
        field.maxLength = 40;
    } else if (option == 'state') {
        field.value = field.value.substr(0, 2); // before reducing the maxlength, make sure it contains at most two characters; you could also reset the value altogether
        field.maxLength = 2;
    }
}​
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<select id="searchtype" name="searchtype" onchange="changeValue(this);">
```

Comment: size and maxlength are two different attributes fo input tag. and he wants to change size not maxlength.

Comment: @PriyankPatel Quote: "All I want to do is limit a form input to 2 characters" - setting the `maxlength` limits the form input. Setting the `size` only changes the appearance.

Comment: yeah. I want to limit the user to only 2 characters for state. Although I realized what I really should be doing is giving them a dropdown list of states if they choose to search by state

Comment: @PriyankPatel nay, limiting to only 2 characters means setting the maximum length; updating the display size, although related, is optional; and it turns out a state drop down would be even better :)

Comment: I'll get to work on trying to figure out the dropdown for the states. I'm sure you'll be seeing another question from me real soon. lol. Thanks

Comment: @whatdafrak no problem, at least take my code along; it simplifies a few things and fixes others :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function changeValue() {
    var option2 = document.getElementById('searchtype').options[document.getElementById('searchtype').selectedIndex].id;
    if (option2 == ("A") || option2 == ("B")) {
        document.getElementById('field').size = "40";
    }
    else if (option2 == "C") {
        document.getElementById('field').size = "2";
    }
}​
```

Comment: Very close. I have 2 problems now though. The input field defaults to some other length until I select an option and then go back to that option for the first option. The last two work but my second problem is I think PriyankPatel is right. I want to limit the maxlength and size

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
document.getElementById('field').setAttribute('size', "10");
```